# Notepad++ Remove everything before the : string?

Tags: notepad++

I have a file like so...

> user@hotmail.com:password

I would like to remove the hotmail address and just keep the password with no :

So the file will look like the following in a nice list..

> passwords
>   passwords

Comment: Are they on separate lines?

Answer (score 12):

Use the find and replace option (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>):

Use the **Regular Expression** mode and replace `.*:` with an empty string.

This will result in a list of passwords which are line seperated.

Then, if you want to remove the new-lines switch to **Extended *\n, \r ...)** mode and replace `\n` with a space. (You might need `\r\n` depending on how you saved your file)

Comment: Propably deserves more then one like

Comment: The Second one on me.